# Scala Upper type bounds implicitly?

Tags: scala, generics, type-inference, type-bounds

I have a first `trait` like this :

```
trait FirstTrait[U] {
  val myVal: U
}
```

And another one as follows :

```
trait SecondTrait[T <: firstTrait[U],U]
```

For the implementation I am doing :

```
case class FirstImpl(myVal: MyType) extends FirstTrait[MyType]

object SecondImpl extends SecondTrait[FirstImpl,MyType]
```

Is there a better way to do the same thing, I would like to simplify my implementation of the second trait like this if possible :

```
object SecondImpl extends SecondTrait[FirstImpl]
```

**EDIT**

I am using after both type in a function :

```
  def func[T <: FirstTrait[U],U](myVal: T): U
```

When I use existential type, I have to explicit types or I get an `"inferred type arguments [FirstImpl,Nothing] do not conform to method func"` error.

So this is how I have to implement the function :

```
val myVal : MyType = MyType()
func[FirstImpl,MyType](FirstImpl(myVal))
```

Can anything simplify?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> def func[T <: FirstTrait[U],U](myVal: T): U
> ```

The problem is that the type of `myVal` doesn't mention `U`, so the compiler is failing to infer it simultaneously with `T`. If it inferred `T` first, it could get `U` from it, but it doesn't currently work this way.

However, `T` is actually useless here and it can be rewritten as

```
def func[U](myVal: FirstTrait[U]): U
```

You can already pass any subtype of `FirstTrait[U]` here and lose the source of the type inference problem.

If this is a simplified signature, a trick which can work is mentioning `U` in the parameter type even if it should be redundant:

```
def func[T <: FirstTrait[U], U](myVal: T with FirstTrait[U]): U
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try existential type

```
trait FirstTrait[U] {
  type _U = U
  val myVal: U
}

trait SecondTrait[T <: FirstTrait[_]]

case class FirstImpl(myVal: MyType) extends FirstTrait[MyType]

object SecondImpl extends SecondTrait[FirstImpl]

def func[T <: FirstTrait[_]](myVal: T): myVal._U = ???

func(FirstImpl(myVal)): MyType
```

or

```
trait FirstTrait {
  type U
  val myVal: U
}

trait SecondTrait[T <: FirstTrait]

case class FirstImpl(myVal: MyType) extends FirstTrait { type U = MyType }

object SecondImpl extends SecondTrait[FirstImpl]

def func[T <: FirstTrait](myVal: T): myVal.U = ???

func(FirstImpl(myVal)): MyType
```

or

```
def func[T, U](myVal: T)(implicit ev: T <:< FirstTrait[U]): U = ???
```

Comment: Thanks, I used existential type and it's works ! But my problem was transferred elsewhere. I have edited my question if you have any idea

Comment: @LucE Can you change definition of `func` to `def func[T <: FirstTrait[_]](myVal: T): Any = ???`? Then `func(FirstImpl(myVal))` should compile without specifying type parameters explicitly.

Comment: No it's really important to my need to have the type of return. Maybe the compilator can't to do what i want

Comment: @LucE With my second approach you can define `def func[T <: FirstTrait](myVal: T): myVal.U = ???` Then `func(FirstImpl(myVal))` compiles and has type `MyType`.

Comment: @LucE Or with first approach you can add type `_U`: `trait FirstTrait[U] {
    type _U = U;
    val myVal: U
  }` and define `def func[T <: FirstTrait[_]](myVal: T): myVal._U = ???`. Then again `func(FirstImpl(myVal))` compiles and has type `MyType`.

Comment: Thank you, that is really good thoughts. I solved my question with your answer by the existantial type and the answer of @alexey-romanov with the trick mentioning U in the parameter, which is simpler to implement

Comment: @LucE One more variant besides AlexeyRomanov's one is `def func[T, U](myVal: T)(implicit ev: T <:< FirstTrait[U]): U = ???`